# Usage of "Do not mistake this for that"

Tags: ambiguity

Take the sentence

> Do not mistake genius for passion.

In this case, what has the person being spoken to mistaken: genius or passion?

Comment: They may already have agreed about someone's genius. The speaker says, "S/he may be a genius but that doesn't mean s/he has passion". The *second* word  - in this case 'passion' -  has probably not hitherto been mentioned. The person spoken to may have given the impression he thought the subject of their talk possessed both qualities.

Comment: It might help you see that *mistake* is immediately next to *genius*. Someone may have made a mistake about genius. No capitals needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! When asking questions, it is important to state the source of a phrase. Did you write it yourself or did you read it somewhere? If you read it, do you have a link to the text? I ask because this sentence appears to be the wrong way around in conventional terms. It usually would make more sense to say, Do not mistake Passion for Genius..

Comment: To corroborate what @Yosef Baskin says, the answer may well be in the title of your question: 'Do not mistake this for that'. 'This' expresses proximity in space and/or time and/or emotions, whereas 'that' expresses distance in space and/or time and/or emotions. In other words, 'Do not mistake this 'thing/idea/...' [which is what you think (here, ‘genius’), because of its proximity in your mind] for that 'thing' [which is at a distance in your mind, and thus considered a second interpretation of the situation (passion) ]. I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica yes, after reading the answer below I understand now that I have the sentence the other way around. I wrote it myself. The other day, someone called me a genius when I was talking about a subject of my interest, and I wanted to tell him that I'm simply passionate about the subject, not a genius. I tried to convey it in the form above, but found that I couldn't. Thus, I came here after failing to find another source online.

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank you for clarifying, and yes I made a mistake with the capitals, I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these perhaps more intuitive sentences:

1. Do not mistake something that glitters for gold.
2. Do not mistake gold for something that glitters.

The first sentence means "not all that glitters is gold" - if you see something that glitters, don't mistake it for a piece of gold, because it might not be.

The second sentence means "not all gold glitters", which makes less sense, as gold *is* something that glitters.

So, "don't mistake X for Y" means that "not all X are Y" or "X does not imply Y". When saying something of this nature, it is implied that you have correctly identified X, but that doesn't indicate Y. Here, "Don't mistake genius for passion" means that people who are indeed geniuses may or may not be passionate, so you should not assume that every genius is also passionate.

Comment: Aha, so that means I have it the other way around. The other day I was talking to a friend about a subject of personal interest. He called me a genius, so I wanted to tell him that I'm simply passionate about the subject, not a genius (but I couldn't figure out how to express it in the form above). Thus, my sentence should be "Do not mistake passion for genius"

Answer (score 1):

HussamAlhassan - Your following comment indicates that you wish to re-order your sentence. Therefore I will deal with that.

> after reading the answer below I understand now that I have the
> sentence the other way around. I wrote it myself. The other day,
> someone called me a genius when I was talking about a subject of my
> interest, and I wanted to tell him that I'm simply passionate about
> the subject, not a genius. I tried to convey it in the form above, but
> found that I couldn't. Thus, I came here after failing to find another
> source online.  HussamAlhassan

The verb "mistake" means to "miss take", that is to take something incorrectly.

So (following the re-ordering suggested in your comment quoted above), we are really saying

Do not incorrectly take passion to be genius

Another way to express the sentiment would be as in the following passage (by me)

Do not take mere passion as an indicator of genius. Passion is required of course but so is hard work!

or in the original format

Do not mistake (mere) passion for genius. Passion is not enough, hard work is even more important.

Comment: Considering your well-deserved reputation, I was wondering whether you could take a step back and answer the original "What has the person being spoken to mistaken?" Your answer now looks like the solution to the restated intention, which reverses the order.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin - If you read the comment at the start of this answer, the OP states that the phrase *should* be reversed and was incorrectly written to begin with. Nevertheless I'll take account of your comment and add something about this. P.S. I've explicitly mentioned the reordering now.